# I Can't imoprt org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I created a Spring MVC web application with the Spring tools suite and I am trying to create this class but when I do the import I get this error:

```
The import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController cannot be resolved
```

This is the class i am trying to create:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;


public class HelloController extends AbstractController {}
```

I use the spring version 4.3.8

Comment: You shouldn't be using that class anyway. It's obsolete. But it just probably means you haven't added the required library in your build path.

Comment: Do you have `spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: @JBNizet, don't think `AbstractController` is deprecated. I know `BaseCommandController` and its sub-classes are deprecated in favor of annotations. Am seeing all the parent classes are still part of spring-webmvc here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Why do you even want to extend that class? I mean there's already a `@Controller` annotation for it.